# How can I retrieve the LAN adapter MAC address?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I want to retrieve the MAC address from a Windows system, only for LAN Adapter. Can you suggest to me how I'd handle this in VBScript?

I'm currently using this VBScript for getting the MAC address, but this is giving me results for all adapters, while I only want the MAC address when I am connected with LAN Adapter.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration") 
For Each objItem in colItems
  If objItem.ServiceName <> "VMnetAdapter" AND isNull(objItem.MACAddress)=0 Then  
    Wscript.Echo objItem.MACAddress
    Wscript.Echo objItem.ServiceName
  End if
Next
```

Comment: Please dont tag this with "java" if question is not related to java programming!

Comment: Ok Sorry !
Can i get some idea related with my Question Sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class instead of the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class. The latter doesn't have a property providing the adapter name.

```
adaptername = "LAN Adapter"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetConnectionID = '" & adaptername & "'" 
For Each adapter In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If Not IsNull(adapter.MACAddress) Then Wscript.Echo adapter.MACAddress
Next
```

Comment: small suggestion

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE (NetConnectionID like '%LAN Adapter%') or (NetConnectionID like '%Local Area Connection%')"

Comment: Thanks Its Working  but if we are changing our Local Area Connection  Adapter Name from Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections then its not working.

Comment: @AlokSingh If you want to select by adapter name you need to know the adapter name. If you change the adapter name you need to adjust the name in your script.

Comment: but i want do define system independent in our application,is there any other way ??

Comment: You'd need to identify a common criterion or property across all systems.

Comment: Urgent ! 
I check you script but its not working when adapter is disable.

Answer (score 1):

how about this

way 1:

if possible try to exclude all not required adapters (excluded VmWare and VirtualBox). of couse, on some computers could be more specific adapters which you need to find out and exclude

```
strComputer = "."  
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")  
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")  
For Each objItem in colItems  
    if objItem.ServiceName <> "VMnetAdapter" and objItem.ServiceName <> "VBoxNetAdp" and objItem.ServiceName <> "" and isNull(objItem.MACAddress) = 0 Then  
            Wscript.Echo objItem.ServiceName & vbCrLf & objItem.MACAddress
    End if    
Next
```

way 2:

find all adapters which has specific gateway

```
strComputer = "."  
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")  
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")  
For Each objItem in colItems  
    if objItem.ServiceName <> "VMnetAdapter" and objItem.ServiceName <> "VBoxNetAdp" and objItem.ServiceName <> "" and isNull(objItem.MACAddress) = 0 Then  
        For Each strIP in objItem.DefaultIPGateway
            If strIP = "192.168.1.1" Then
                    Wscript.Echo objItem.ServiceName & vbCrLf & objItem.MACAddress
            End If
        Next
    End if    
Next
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ZAM ...
Way 1 is not giving only  MAC ID of LAN Adapter,I am getting all the MAC ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,you will get MAC Address of LAN Adapter Only,

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE (NetConnectionID like '%Local Area Connection%')"
For Each adapter In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  If Not IsNull(adapter.MACAddress) Then Wscript.Echo adapter.MACAddress
Next
```

I am using this code only and its working fine.